# Can [parameters] be inserted dynamically into paths in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, next-router

I'm running into a problem trying to get routes working with `[params]`/`:params`.

The paths I'm working with will always be structured as follows:
`console/sites/[siteId]/possibly-another-directory/page`.

The `console/sites` portion I can set as `basePath` in *next.config.js* but the `[siteId]` is something I would rather not have to manually add to every path in order to not end up with `console/sites/possibly-another-directory/page`. Is there a single place I can set this so that it will be included in every path I link to from within my site?

FWIW, I've tried setting my `basePath` to `/console/sites/:siteId` but `:siteId` was being read as a literal value.

Comment: You can't have dynamic values as `basePath`, if that's what you're asking. Do you even need to do that though? Couldn't you structure your `pages` folder in a way that would suit those requirements?

Comment: @juliomalves I was saying that I *had* tried adding a dynamic value into my `basePath` but that didn't work, as you've noted. What I'm trying to find is a way to avoid having to include a reference to the `siteId` in every Link's href since it will remain fairly constant once the site loads, just as the `basePath` is going to be constant. I would like to avoid a situation where a Link is added to the site but the dev forgets to insure that the path begins with `pathId` as it will need to (i.e., `\`/${pathId}/directory/page\``). So far I haven't found a solution to this problem though.